# How to enable ALB stickiness as per user IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Can we enable stickiness on alb as per the source IP? What I am trying to do is, if a user hits the endpoint then he should stick with the same target group.

I split the traffic 50/50 on the `/dev` endpoint in AWS ALB but I want to stick the user to the target group he gets on his first request.

Answer (score 0):

AWS ALB only supports cookie based stickiness (at this time). IP won't always identify a single user, as thousands of people in an office building sharing an Internet connection may all have the same public IP address.

Comment: So I have 90/10 traffic split using weighted target groups. I think I can't use a cookie with weighted target groups right? So what are my different option?